# if container width is larger than images inside. How can i use flexbox so that in the following, only two images are display per row?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
body {
  background-image: url('../images/dust_scratches.png');
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #777777;
}

.wrapper {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  max-width: 960px;
  padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  max-height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="assets/css/style.css" />
</head>

<body>

  <div class="wrapper">


    <a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/247x208"></a>
    <a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/247x208"></a>
    <a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/247x208"></a>
    <a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/247x208"></a>
    <a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/247x208"></a>


  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

So I want to use flexbox on this if possible. But on initial page load providing its full screen I want to display only two of the images per row, and then the last row is only one image. However if i shrink the page, it does adjust responsively.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: `<div class=".wrapper">` is that a typo? Also currently you set flex on `body` instead of `wrapper`

Comment: use `flex-wrap:wrap`

Comment: sorry @Huangism yes typo.

Comment: @TemaniAfif flex-wrap will only wrap if the content doesn't fit in row no? How will it wrap if content fits?

Comment: @user2763557 if you need to wrap, add a div for every 2 items and set the div to width 100%. Show and hide the div when you need to in order to get the line break you need. Assuming you added flex-wrap already